# Can't connect to Lambda or EC2 from my local computer through python requests

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'm new at AWS and I'm trying to deploy a simple lambda service and call it from my local computer.

Lambda:

```
import json
import pandas
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    message = 'Hello {} {}!'.format(event['first_name'], 
                                    event['last_name'])  
    return { 
        'message' : message
    }
```

When I run a test on AWS env it does work, but when I try to do the same kind of test on python I get the 502 error with rest API on API gateway, and error 500 on HTTP API also on API gateway.

Test AWS:
{
"first_name": "alooo",
"last_name": "arrombado"
}

Local Python Test:

```
import resquests
r2 = requests.post('https://ia81y8e8ye.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/default/PortAPI',
                   json = {'first_name':'jose','last_name':'example'})
r2
<Response [502]>
```

The same kind of problem happen on EC2 instance when try to deploy an python flask API.

With Lambda I didn't use any kind of permission, so I think it has a open traffic. In other hand, in EC2 I set inbound and outbound, all communications to anywhere.

I don't know if more info is needed.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just updated answer with example of a function. Hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the following:

```
print(r2.content)
```

you will see that you get:

```
b'{"message": "Internal server error"}'
```

This likely means that your **lambda most likely failed**. In that case you have to check CloudWatch Logs and search for any error message.

And this can happen because you may be using incorrect `event` in your function, and/or [returning incorrect response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format) type. Structure of event object for proxy integration is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html) for reference. Other reason could by missing `pandas` in your lambda.

#### Example of correct lambda function

Assuming lambda proxy integration, the correct function would be:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):    
    
    body = json.loads(event['body'])
    
    print(body)
    
    message = 'Hello {} {}!'.format(body['first_name'], 
                                    body['last_name'])  
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        'body' : message
    }
```

Comment: Can u post the right format to me, to send a python request? Like the example I posted?

Comment: @AlexandreGentil Hi. I already provided correct lambda function. It should work with the same request, unless you don't use lambda proxy integration.

Comment: how do I use lambda proxy integration?

Comment: @AlexandreGentil Its the easiest way to use api gateway and lambda. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html).